# Swift : add BigInteger framework

Tags: swift, frameworks, rsa, biginteger

I have to work with huge numbers in swift (to implement RSA algorithm), so I'm looking for an equivalent to the Java's BigInteger class. In an other topic, I found this one : https://github.com/kirsteins/BigInteger 
So I'm trying to add this to my project following these steps :
- I download and add the BigInteger.xcodeproj to my project
In "Build Phases" :
- Add "BigInteger" at "Target Dependencies"
- Add "BigInteger.framework from 'BigInteger' target in 'BigInteger' project" to "Link Binary With Libraries"
- Add "BigInteger.framework" to the "Copy Files"

When I build the project, it "Build failed", but I cannot understand why there is a problem. I found a video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBmfGdbOrMs describing the steps, I follow exactly these steps but the problem is still here...

Do you have the same problem ? Do you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a big integer and big double implementation for swift, that doesn't require any additional library. Just copy it into your project. It supports whole Numbers (BInt) and Fractions (BDouble) with most of the common math operators like addition, subtraction, multiplication, exponentiation, modulus and division. Some optimized math functions like factorial or gcd are also implemented.

Here are some code examples:

```
// Create a new number:
let num = BInt(232)
print(num) // prints "232"

// You can also use Strings to create a number:
let veryBig = BInt("-827846184963421874362418746238453267452971345218746328715380000000000")

// Every standard math operator works well, even with normal Integers
// Visit the github page for more informations
let v0 = (BInt(5) + BInt(4)) - BInt(3)
let v1 = veryBig * 1000
let v2 = vergBig ^ num
let v3 = (veryBig ^ 50000) / (BInt(2) ^ 900) + 1
let v4 = gcd(abs(veryBig), num)

// BDouble is very similar, you can find a detailed description on Github
let fraction = BDouble("27", over: "31")
print(fraction) // prints "27/31"
```

You can use it freely without giving me credit, and please contribute if you want.

You can find it here: https://github.com/mkrd/Swift-Big-Integer